# Merge 2 SQL queries in Athena

Tags: amazon-athena

I have these SQL queries working as expected in Athena (presto)

```
SELECT target_port_list ,
min(CAST(From_iso8601_timestamp(time) AS timestamp)) as "min_date",
max(CAST(From_iso8601_timestamp(time) AS timestamp)) as "max_date",
max(CAST(From_iso8601_timestamp(time) AS timestamp)) - min(CAST(From_iso8601_timestamp(time) AS timestamp)) as "diff" 
from alb_logs
group by target_port_list
_____

select target_port_list, elb_status_code, count(*) as cnt 
from alb_logs
where request_url = 'https://register.yahoo.in:443/ABC/Registration/Account/Login'
group by target_port_list, elb_status_code
```

Is it possible to merge these 2 queries?
I need diff column from query 1 to be shown next to each targe_port_list in the second query.

Comment: Please provide sample data, current results returned by the two queries, and the output that you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
select a1.target_port_list, a1.elb_status_code, a2.diff , count(*) as cnt 
from alb_logs  as a1 left join
(SELECT target_port_list ,
min(CAST(From_iso8601_timestamp(time) AS timestamp)) as "min_date",
max(CAST(From_iso8601_timestamp(time) AS timestamp)) as "max_date",
max(CAST(From_iso8601_timestamp(time) AS timestamp)) - min(CAST(From_iso8601_timestamp(time) AS timestamp)) as "diff" 
from alb_logs 
group by target_port_list) as a2 on a2.target_port_list = a1.target_port_list 
where a1.request_url = 'https://register.yahoo.in:443/ABC/Registration/Account/Login'
group by a1.target_port_list, a1.elb_status_code, a2.diff
```